# Maximise $\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \cdot i \right) - \left( \max_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot j \right)$ with $p$ permutation of size $n$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, permutations, contest-math, discrete-optimization

I'm trying to maximise the following value:

$\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \cdot i \right) - \left( \max_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot j \right)$

where $p$ is an array consisting of $n$ distinct integers from $1$ to $n$ in arbitrary order (a permutation of $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$). I have to find an optimal permutation $p$.

---

A brute force approach in Python can allow us detect a pattern:

```
from __future__ import annotations  # noqa
from itertools import permutations  # noqa

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n in range(1, 12):
        elements = range(1, n+1)
        perms = permutations(elements, n)
        best: int = 0
        best_perm: list[int] | None = None
        for perm in perms:
            perm: list[int] = list(perm)
            s = 0
            max = 0
            for i in range(0, n):
                s += (i+1) * perm[i]
                if (i+1) * perm[i] > max:
                    max = (i+1) * perm[i]
            s -= max
            if s >= best:
                best = s
                best_perm = perm
        print(f"{n=}, {best_perm=}, {best=}")
```

Outputs:

```
n=1, best_perm=[1], best=0
n=2, best_perm=[2, 1], best=2
n=3, best_perm=[1, 3, 2], best=7
n=4, best_perm=[1, 4, 3, 2], best=17
n=5, best_perm=[1, 2, 5, 4, 3], best=35
n=6, best_perm=[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4], best=62
n=7, best_perm=[1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4], best=100
n=8, best_perm=[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5], best=152
n=9, best_perm=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6], best=219
n=10, best_perm=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7], best=303
n=11, best_perm=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 9, 8], best=406
```

We can notice that the numbers in the permutation "go up", then "go down starting from $n$". It makes sense (small numbers in the beginning, and we can't put the largest number at the end since there is the $\max_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot j$ term subtracted in the function we are trying to maximise). Could it potentially fail for large values of $n$? However, I have thoroughly tested all computationally-feasible cases and have not discovered a counterexample.

I'm struggling to find a proof. This post is adapted from the Problem - C competition from [codeforces](https://codeforces.com/contest/1859/problem/C) that ended on the 12th of August 2023.

EDIT: I'm looking for a proof of the *pattern*, but there might be a proof to find an permutation that maximises the value we are trying to maximise, which would be even more satisfying.

Comment: Up to 100: 0 2 7 17 35 62 100 152 219 303 406 530 678 851 1051 1280 1540 1834 2163 2529 2934 3380 3869 4403
4985 5616 6298 7033 7823 8670 9576 10544 11575 12671 13834 15066 16369 17745 19196 20724 22332
24021 25793 27650 29594 31627 33751 35968 38280 40690 43199 45809 48522 51340 54265 57299 60444
63702 67075 70565 74175 77906 81760 85739 89845 94080 98446 102945 107579 112349 117260 122312
127507 132847 138334 143970 149757 155697 161792 168044 174455 181025 187762 194662 201730 208967
216375 223952 231712 239645 247757 256037 264526 273187 282033 291071 300300 309722 319339 329153

Comment: Note that the maximizing permutation may not be unique. For example, for $n=7$, both $(1,2,3,7,6,5,4)$ and $(1,2,3,4,7,6,5)$ yield the maximum output value of $100$.

Comment: The _pattern_ makes sense, as according to the rearrangement inequality $\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \cdot i \right)$ is maximized when $p_i=i$. With this in mind, the best way to minimize $\left( \max_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot j \right)$ while still maximizing 
$\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \cdot i \right)$ is ordering the biggest positive integers $\{p_m,p_{m+1},...,p_n\}$ in descending order, such that $\left( \max_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot j \right)+\left( \sum_{i=m}^{n} p_{i}^2 -\sum_{i=m}^{n} p_{i} \cdot (n-m+i) \right)$ is minimized.

Comment: I would suggest posting this on Math Overflow. I think it's interesting enough, and maybe they will come up with a complete solution there.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Yes that could be a good idea, although I'm sort of struggling to follow Mehdi and your answer already (not because the answers aren't good but rather because this might be slightly beyond my combinatorics skills).

Comment: @RobPratt Could you add this sequence to OEIS? Since you computed it.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein I submitted to OEIS just now.

Comment: Posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458129/maximizing-a-sum-minus-its-maximal-summand

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein https://oeis.org/A367185

Answer (score 6):

This is not a full proof but I hope it provides some insight

If we assume the optimal solution is in form of

$p_i = \begin{cases}
        i & \text{if  }~~i=1,2,...,m\\
        n+m+1-i & \text{if}~~i=m+1,...,n
    \end{cases}$

for $i>m$, it we can show that $a_i = ip_i$ has maximum at $i=\lceil \frac{m+n}{2} \rceil$. This can be shown considering the fact that $a_i = ip_i$ is a concave function of $i$ and

$i^* = \min_{i>m} {a_{i+1}\le a_{i}}$.

$a_{i+1}\le a_i \Rightarrow (i+1)(n+m-i)\le i(n+m+1-i) \Rightarrow i\ge \frac{n+m}{2} \Rightarrow i^* = \lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil$.

Also it is clear that $a_i>a_j$ if $i>m$ and $j\le m$. Therefore, $\max_{i \in \{1,2,..,n\}}{a_i} =\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil (n+m+1-\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil) =\begin{cases}
        (\frac{n+m}{2})(\frac{n+m}{2}+1) & \text{if  }~~n+m~~\text{even}\\
        (\frac{n+m+1}{2})^2 & \text{if}~~~~n+m~~\text{odd}
    \end{cases}$

Now, we try to find the the value of $m$ that maximizes our objective function

$f(m)=\sum_{i=1}^m i^2 + \sum_{i=m+1}^n a_i - a_{\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil}$. We further simplify as
$f(m)=\sum_{i=1}^m i^2 - \sum_{i=m+1}^n i^2+ (n+m+1)\sum_{i=m+1}^n i  - a_{\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil} = 2\sum_{i=1}^m i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n i^2+ (n+m+1)\sum_{i=m+1}^n i  - a_{\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil}$
$=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{3}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{(n+m+1)^2(n-m)}{2}-a_{\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil}$. It is easy to show that this function is also concave as

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = (4m+2)-(n+3m+2)-\frac{1}{2}=-(n-m+\frac{1}{2})<0$. So,

$m^* = min_m {f(m+1)\le f(m)}$.

$f(m+1)\le f(m) \Rightarrow 2\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n i^2+ (n+m+2)\sum_{i=m+2}^n i  - a_{\lceil \frac{n+m+1}{2} \rceil} \le 2\sum_{i=1}^m i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n i^2+ (n+m+1)\sum_{i=m+1}^n i  - a_{\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil}$

$\Rightarrow 2(m+1)^2 - (n+m+1)(m+1) + \sum_{i=m+2}^n i + a_{\lceil \frac{n+m}{2} \rceil}-a_{\lceil \frac{n+m+1}{2} \rceil}\le 0$

$\Rightarrow -(n-m-1)(m+1) + \frac{(n+m+2)(n-m-1)}{2} - \lceil \frac{n+m+1}{2} \rceil\le 0$

$\text{if  }~~n+m~~\text{even} \Rightarrow {(n-m)^2 -n+m} - 2 -n -m \le 0 \Rightarrow (n-m)^2 \le 2n+2) \rightarrow m\ge n-\sqrt{2n+2}$

$\text{if  }~~n+m~~\text{odd} \Rightarrow {(n-m)^2 -n+m} - 1 -n -m \le 0 \Rightarrow (n-m)^2 \le 2n+1 \rightarrow m\ge n-\sqrt{2n+1}$

It can be shown that $m^* = n- \lfloor \sqrt{2n+1}\rfloor$ is the solution for any case. Hence, the optimal solution of proposed form is:

$p_i = \begin{cases}
        i & \text{if  }~~i=1,2,...,n- \lfloor \sqrt{2n+1}\rfloor\\
        2n- \lfloor \sqrt{2n+1}\rfloor+1-i & \text{if}~~i=n- \lfloor \sqrt{2n+1}\rfloor+1,...,n
    \end{cases}$

Answer (score 3):

This solution is slightly handwave-y and complements the [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4757038/499816) by Mehdi by attempting to show that the conjectured structure of the maximizing permutation $p$ is correct. I may return later to make it more rigorous.

For a permutation $p\in S_n$, denote $f(p)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}ip_i\right)-\left(\max_{1\le i\le n}ip_i\right)$.

Suppose that $\max_{1\le i\le n} ip_i = i_0p_{i_0}$ for some $i_0\in[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. This means that $ip_i\le i_0p_{i_0}$ for all $i\in[n]$. In particular, this implies that
$$
\begin{split}
p(i)<p_{i_0} \qquad &\text{if} \qquad i\in[i_0+1,n],\\
i<i_0 \qquad &\text{if} \qquad p_i\in[p_{i_0}+1,n],
\end{split}
$$

===***begin handwave 1***===

Therefore, to maximize $f(p)$ while keeping the $\max_{1\le i\le n}ip_i$ at the same position $i_0$ and value $p_{i_0}$, we should aim to place the values $p_i$ greater than $p_{i_0}$ as far to the right as possible (given the constraints), i.e. place the interval $H$ of those values immediately to the left of $p_{i_0}$, and then partition the values less than $p_{i_0}$ into two intervals, $M$ and $L$, so that all values in $M$ are greater than all values in $L$, all values in $M$ are to the right of $p_{i_0}$, and all values in $L$ are to the left of $H$. We may denote this by
$$
p=L\oplus(H\ominus \{p_{i_0}\}\ominus M),
$$
where $\oplus$ and $\ominus$ denote the direct sum and the skew-sum of intervals, respectively.

===***end handwave 1***===

We know that $|H|=n-p_{i_0}$ and $|M|=n-i_0$, so $$|H\ominus\{p_{i_0}\}\ominus M|=(n-p_{i_0})+1+(n-i_0)=2n+1-(i_0+p_{i_0}),$$ and thus $|L|=n-|H\ominus\{p_{i_0}\}\ominus M|=(i_0+p_{i_0})-n-1$.

Now we want to show that $|p_{i_0}-i_0|\le 1$. Suppose this is false, then either $i_0<p_{i_0}-1$ or $p_{i_0}<i_0-1$.

If $i_0<p_{i_0}-1$, then $i_0<n$, so $p_{i_0}-1$ should be placed to the right of $p_{i_0}$, say, in position $i_1>i_0$. Then
$i_1(p_{i_0}-1)\le i_0p_{i_0}$, so
$$
0<i_1-i_0\le\frac{i_0p_{i_0}}{p_{i_0}-1}-i_0=\frac{i_0}{p_{i_0}-1}<1,
$$
which is impossible.

Similarly, if $p_{i_0}<i_0-1$, then $p_{i_0}<n$, so $p_{i_0-1}>p_{i_0}$. We know that $(i_0-1)p_{i_0-1}\le i_0p_{i_0}$, so
$$
0<p_{i_0-1}-p_{i_0}\le\frac{i_0p_{i_0}}{i_0-1}-p_{i_0}=\frac{p_{i_0}}{i_0-1}<1,
$$
which is impossible.

Thus, $|p_{i_0}-i_0|\le 1$. This splits into two cases: either $p_{i_0}=i_0$, or $p_{i_0}=i_0\pm 1$. In the second case, by the same argument as above, we should also have $p_{i_0\pm 1}=i_0$, where the signs ($+$ or $-$) must agree.

Thus, we can modify the notation for the parts of $p$ slightly. In the two-line notation, we have
$$
p=
\begin{pmatrix}
L & M & C & H\\
L & H & C & M
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $L<M<C<H$ (i.e. every value in $L$ is less than every value in $M$, etc.), $|H|=|M|$, and
$$
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
i_0\\
i_0
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad \text{or} \qquad
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
i_0-1 & i_0\\
i_0 & i_0-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also, since the $p$ maps the interval $L$ to itself, the maximizing permutation should have the entries of $L$ in increasing order, i.e. $p$ begins with $(1,2,\dots,|L|)$.

Finally, we show that the values in the intervals $H$ and $M$ should be in decreasing order (while their positions are in increasing order, of course) close enough to the maximizing value of $i_0$.

===***begin handwave 2***===

Once this is shown, we should show that if $i_0$ is far enough away from the maximizing value (i.e., too small), then it can be increased in a way that yields a permutation $p$ with a higher $f(p)$.

===***end handwave 2***===

We will only work out the case when $p_{i_0}=i_0$, since the other case is similar, with resulting values that are almost the same. We will also only show that $M$ must be in decreasing order, as the argument for the values in $H$ is very similar. Suppose that the values of $M$ are not in decreasing order in the positions in $H$. Then there exists some $j>0$ such that $p_{i_0+1+j}\ge i_0-j$. Recall that
$$
i_0^2=i_0p_{i_0}>(i_0+1+j)p_{i_0+1+j}\ge (i_0+1+j)(i_0-j)=i_0^2-j^2-j+i_0,
$$
so
$$
j^2+j-i_0>0
$$
for some value $j\in[n-i_0-1]$. Thus, to prevent that from happening for any $j\in[n-i_0-1]$, we need to choose $i_0$ so that
$$
(n-i_0-1)^2+(n-i_0-1)-i_0<0,
$$
i.e.
$$
i_0^2-2ni_0+n^2-n<0.
$$
This implies that $i_0\in[n-\sqrt{n},n+\sqrt{n}]$, but since, obviously, $i_0\le n$ and $i_0\in\mathbb{N}$, we simply have
$$
i_0\ge n-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor.
$$
Thus, the values in both $H$ and $M$ must be in decreasing order if $i_0\ge n-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$, which makes the length of the decreasing segment $\le 2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor+2$, and this bound is well above $\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n+1}\right\rfloor$.

That, more or less, ends this (sketch of a) proof.

Comment: I might be wrong, but handwave 1 seems to be enough to give strong intuition about the pattern "values go up [$L$] and then down [$H$, $p_{i0}$ and $M$]", isn't it? Assuming $L$ is in increasing order and the intervals $H$ and $M$ should be in decreasing order (while their positions are in increasing order, of course).

Comment: Not saying the rest is useless since it rigorously proves the assumptions at the end of my first comment, but from an intuitive point of view, if I had to make sense of the logic of the pattern, handwave 1 seems to do the job - at least it did for me.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows So, it looks like values go up $[L]$, then there is $[H]$ in some order, then $p_{i_0}=i_0$ on the main diagonal or $p_{i_0-1}=i_0, p_{i_0}=i_0-1$ on the first superdiagonal and subdiagonal, then $[M]$ in some order. Moreover, that order must be decreasing if the length of $H$ (and $M$) is at most $\sqrt{n}$. But if it's over $\sqrt{n}$, then I think you have to show that you can increase $i_0$ so that $f(p)$ increases. It was way past midnight when I got to that point, and I gave up. Hence, the handwaves. But it's an interesting problem, I like it!

Comment: Alexander, I believe that you and I must have temporarily swapped brains a couple nights ago! This looks like a proof that I would have attempted, and I instead ended up in a rabbit hole about permutation patterns >.< A couple revisions and I think I've finally patched the holes in my argument, so I'll post that later today.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I was also thinking about how to tie patterns to this. There might even be a paper somewhere in there, but I'm just not seeing right now how to generalize it nicely.